# gwtupload missing implement

Tags: java, gwt, gwtupload

I'm using the gwtupload library to change the standard upload Form. Basically I just want to create a widget with an image and change it on :hover and :active via css.

```
public class FileUploadFormImpl extends FileUploadForm implements HasClickHandler {

  private SingleUploader fileUpload;

  public FileUploadFormImplCostum(String actionUrl) {
    setAction(actionUrl);
    // Create Panel with costum Button
    DecoratorPanel widget = new DecoratorPanel();
    widget.setSize("100%", "100%");
    widget.setStyleName("costum-Button");

    // Create a FileUpload widget.
    fileUpload = new SingleUploader(FileInputType.CUSTOM.with(widget));
    fileUpload.setStyleName("costum-Button"); 
    fileUpload.setWidth("100%");

    fileUpload.getWidget().setSize("100%", "100%);");

    add(fileUpload);
  }
    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }
```

The projects builds but doesn't run I'm getting the error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Button should implement HasClickHandlers
```

But I'm having a click handler and it's basically the same as on the library [example code page](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/CustomWidgets). I don't get it is my implementation wrong or do I miss something. Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing to `FileInputType.CUSTOM.with` method the DecoratorPanel that don't implements HasClickHandlers.

Comment: hmm..yeah. fixed it. thought my widget would just be my css background-image and not the image + a send button. I want to get rid off this button. btw thx man your are saving my day :)

Comment: fixed. in relation to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515163/gwtupload-input-type-costum